# Batmanacci: a Fibonacci sequence, but with letters

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, computer-science, dynamic-programming, combinatorics-on-words

I stumbled upon [the Batmanacci problem (via kattis.com)](https://open.kattis.com/problems/batmanacci), where we have a Fibonacci sequence that starts with $a_1 = \text{'N'}$ and $a_2 = \text{'A'}$, and uses concatenation instead of addition. We need to know what $k$-th letter of the $n$-th term in the sequence is.

Because string concatenation takes too long, the following is the correct [solution by Michael Pfeifer (via github.com)](https://github.com/mpfeifer1/Kattis/blob/master/batmanacci.py), that I do not understand:

> The algorithm for the solution of this problem is the following:
>
> Instead of letters we say that we have $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 1$ and then $a_3 = a_1 + a_2$.
>
> To get the letter out of the sequence of these sums we then do  (Python code):
>
> ```
> while n > 2:
>    if k > fib[n-2]:
>        k -= fib[n-2]
>        n -= 1
>    else:
>        n -= 2
> ```
>
> Where `fib` is the list of the sums, `n` is the number of sums (length of the list), and `k` is the letter position of the letter we want to get (if we look all the list as one long word).
>
> Then if at the end of the loop n is equal to 2, the letter is "A" and if n is equal to 1, then the letter is "N".

However I do not understand how this solution works.

Comment: What is the source of that solution?

Comment: @Blue Glad you asked, the source is: https://github.com/mpfeifer1/Kattis/blob/master/batmanacci.py

Comment: @Blue Actually any other solution for this problem that I found uses the same method

Comment: The solution is simply undoing the concatenation step that resulted in the $n$th batmanacci string. The $k$th letter in that string must have come from one of the previous two batmanacci strings, i.e. the string with index $n-1$ or $n-2$. Repeat until you get to $n=1$ or $n=2$, the initial letters N or A.

Comment: making sure I understand, it goes "N" "A" "NA" "ANA" "NAANA" "ANANAANA" "NAANAANANAANA"?

Comment: @DanUznanski Yes that is correct

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That procedure is what I don't understand. For me it isn't as obvious where the solution comes from. Can you try to explain why it works?

Comment: Suppose you concatenate "abcde" and "fghi" to get "abcdefghi". The first 5 letters of the "abcdefghi" are the first five letters of "abcde". Letters 6 to 9 of "abcdefghi" are letters 1 to 4 of "fghi". So if I want to know the $k$th letter of "abcdefghi", if $k\le5$ I can just take the $k$th letter of "abcde" and if $k>5$ I can take the $(k-5)$-th letter of "fghi".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ok, but here we make sums from $1$ and $0$, I don't understand, if let's say we then have a number $X$ that is made this way, how do we do it then?

Comment: The sums start at 1 and 1, and they represent the lengths of the Batmanacci strings. There is a leading 0 in the code because arrays in Python are zero-indexed. He starts with fib[1]=fib[2]=1 (and fib[0]=0 which is not used).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis So fib[3] = 2, fib[4] = 3, fib[5] = 5, fib[6] = 8,...

However, let's say that we are interested in a letter that is in fib[6], we only know the numbers, how do we get it from that sum?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis So if I understand correctly for fib[6] = 8, actually means that fib[6] is 8 letters long?

Comment: Yes, that means the 6th Batmanacci string is 8 letters long. That is why the code compares $k$ to fib[n-2], the length of the first part that makes up the $n$th batmanacci string.

Comment: So for example, the 5th letter in ANANAANA=ANA+NAANA is the second letter in NAANA=NA+ANA, which is the second letter in NA=N+A, which is the first letter in A.